# Run ajax call in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

okay so I am making a sort of an online multiplayer game, which requires 4 people to join a lobby.
All is done, but I want the screen to constantly update who has joined the lobby.
here is my function.

```
function lobbyquery(x){
$.ajax({
    url: 'inc/fn/lobbyload.php?lid='+ x,
    success: function(data) {
        var spl = data.split(",")
        var p1 = spl[0];
        var p2 = spl[1];
        var p3 = spl[2];
        var p4 = spl[3];
        var pl = spl[4];
        var pleft = 4 - pl;
        $('#game').html('Player1 : ' + p1 + '<br>Player2 : ' + p2 + '<br>Player3 : ' + p3 + '<br>Player4 : ' + p4 + '<br><Br>' + pleft + ' players left to join.')
      }
});
```

}

I cant find any solution, please help.

Comment: you should be using socket.io

Comment: Avoid polling use sockets instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer for update the DIV every # seconds/ms

```js
setInterval(myMethod(x), 5000);

function myMethod(x)
{
  $.ajax({
    url: 'inc/fn/lobbyload.php?lid='+ x,
    success: function(data) {
      var spl = data.split(",")
      var p1 = spl[0];
      var p2 = spl[1];
      var p3 = spl[2];
      var p4 = spl[3];
      var pl = spl[4];
      var pleft = 4 - pl;
      $('#game').html('Player1 : ' + p1 + '<br>Player2 : ' + p2 + '<br>Player3 : ' + p3 + '<br>Player4 : ' + p4 + '<br><Br>' + pleft + ' players left to join.')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried this, but the problem is that i call for the function on a button click.

Answer (score 0):

you can always set an interval, but a better way to do this would be to check for new players in lobbyload. And when you have a new player added you can execute your lobbyquery update function (or something like it) from your php script.

So logic would be something like:

new player joins > newPlayerToLobby.php

newPlayerToLobby.php calls javascript lobby update function

Comment: okay, this sort of went above my head... can you explain in a little more detail?

Comment: Sure. So there are two main ways of attacking your problem of checking for new players.

1. having the lobby constantly checking if any new players were added.

2. only updating the lobby when a new player is added.

So when each new player joins, you'll want to call your lobbyquery function to refresh the lobby info.